# How to include full screen image in an iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I want to add a full screen image into an iOS app and I want to know the best way to support different devices

The problem with using the image assets: `1x`, `2x`, and `3x` is that `2x` is used for `iPhone4s`, `iPhone5`, and `iPhone6` which every one of them has a different dimensions

Should I use a different images (one for every device) and include them as resources then at runtime I choose the image based on the current device? I feel like it is not a good solution

any suggestions of a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on the asset you can configure more options and sizes depending on various parameters. Conceptually similar to what happens when you create a new LaunchScreen Item in the asset.  See image.

Depending on what is the wanted end results you can also adopt different tactiques, like having a background image that is big enough to be set as "Center" aspect mode and the eventually place other images like logos or titles on top of it. Or again just have one big image that can be set as "AspectFit".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to have a different image for every device. Either use stretching or tiling to handle different sizes, or make an image that you can clip on smaller screen sizes, or you will have to have different images for each device and code to detect which to use and spend time maintaining that whenever new devices are announced.